# PHP regular expression not working - parsing {{tags}}

Tags: php, regex

What I want to do it parse the following string in a way that all placeholders inside `{{}}` are replace by the value indicated by "default". For instance, `{{time, default=noon}}` should become `noon`.

Here's the code I tried:

```
$input = 'It was a {{color, default=black}} and scary {{phase}}. As the {{animals, default=dogs}} {{make_sound, default=barked}} and the trees swayed {{setting, default=to the breeze}}, a {{size, default=}} {{monster, default=troll}} that emerged from the shadows.';
$input = preg_replace('/\{\{.*default=(\w+)\}\}/i', '$1', $input);
echo $input;
```

The output produced is: `Output: It was a troll that emerged from the shadows.`

Why are the remaining patterns not getting parsed correctly?

Comment: because .* is greedy.

Comment: what happens in case of `{{phase}}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Good point! I replaced * with *? and the results have improved. Still not perfect though.

Comment: @vks It crept in because the task is part of a larger problem. Please ignore it for now. :-)

Comment: @dotslash what's your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{[^}]*\bdefault=([^}]*)}}
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aG0sF5/4

Comment: Excellent! But why don't we need to escape the curly brackets here?

Comment: @dotslash coz its inside `[]`.

Comment: I mean, even the ones at the start. Don't they form a min/max group?

Comment: @dotslash Because the only have special meaning as repeat, so only if there is a number between { and }. Eg `a{3}` matches 'aaa', but `a{b}` matches 'a{b}' literately.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels Thanks! I was guessing that much. :)

Comment: @vks Just one last doubt in my mind: Why do we need to guard against `}` both before and after the pattern? I mean, with `[^}]*`?

Comment: @dotslash you can use `.*?` instead but using negation based regex is safest as regex engine can extend `.*?` in some cases though here it wont probably

Answer (score 3):

Because `.*` is greedy. And also a non-greedy regex `.*?` won't work here because `.*?` will also match `}}`.

```
preg_replace('/\{\{(?:(?!\}\}).)*?default=(.*?)\}\}/i', '\1', $input);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zC8mG5/4)

Comment: The first demo isn't working well. I guess it's because of `\w+`?

Comment: yep, I don't know what's your expected output is. At first I thought you only want to replace the tags which contain `default` followed by one or more word chars further followed by `}}`

Comment: Yes, that's the expected output. So `{{phase}}` in my example, stays.

Answer (score 0):

please see the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ2cT4/1)

```
=(.*?)}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HN4oITwYwBVD0kaC)